# Java : prevent System.exit, File access, etc... for user defined expression

Tags: java

In our application, users are able to define Java expressions that are executed by our main engine (those expressions are method calls only: e.g., Math.abs(42) ). They're executed via reflection.

What are the different solutions to prevent those expressions calling for example System.exit (but as well File access and others...) either directly or via a method call that will internally call eventually System.exit ?

Note that several different expressions can be executed in different threads. Preventing for example File access with a SecurityManager does not work as the main engine must still be able to access the File system while the expressions are executed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are wrong to say you can't use the `SecurityManager` -- this is precisely what it's for: hosting untrusted code, as in an Applet container or RMI server. The modern SecurityManager is configured with policy files that grant specific, fine-grained rights, including limited access to the file system. You need to use the SecurityManager, but you need to become an expert in it.

This is an enormous topic; the best thing to do would be to Google "Java security policy files" and just read everything you can.

Answer (score 4):

What you are doing is crazy. Allowing users to execute arbitrary Java code on your machine is an awful idea and there is no way you can make that safe against Hackers who know their stuff.

The only solution I can think of is to create a whitelist of packages and methods that may be used. But trying to blacklist specific actions will never get you there. There is always someone who is smarter than you are when it comes to breaking stuff.

Update: I have now read more about the `SecurityManager` and it seems that you can controll package access very finely with it, so I'd suggest you to go with Ernest's answer.

Comment: I agree with the sentiments -- this is scary stuff -- but rolling your own is less safe than using the platform, IMO.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill the reason I suggested that was that I didn't know how finely grained access control could be with the SecurityManager.

Answer (score 3):

The Java security system is the appropriate tool for this. `SecurityManager` is only a part of this system which you will have to use.

Basically you do not invoke the untrusted code yourself. Instead you will wrap that call into a `PrivilegedAction` and give that to one of the `AccessController.doPrivileged` methods. Then the untrusted code will be executed in another `ProtectionDomain`.

So you have to configure two protection domains: One for your engine with full privileges and one for the untrusted code with reduced privileges.

But as Ernest already mentioned: This is quite complicated stuff and not suited to a Q&A site like this. Read up the appropriate tutorials from Oracle and Co. Use the above keywords for your search.

Answer (score 2):

For example Apache Velocity had a similar problem to solve. They use black listed classes and packages defined in velocity.properties:

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# SECURE INTROSPECTOR
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# If selected, prohibits methods in certain classes and packages from being 
# accessed.
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

introspector.restrict.packages = java.lang.reflect

# The two most dangerous classes

introspector.restrict.classes = java.lang.Class
introspector.restrict.classes = java.lang.ClassLoader

# Restrict these for extra safety

introspector.restrict.classes = java.lang.Compiler
introspector.restrict.classes = java.lang.InheritableThreadLocal
introspector.restrict.classes = java.lang.Package
introspector.restrict.classes = java.lang.Process
introspector.restrict.classes = java.lang.Runtime
introspector.restrict.classes = java.lang.RuntimePermission
introspector.restrict.classes = java.lang.SecurityManager
introspector.restrict.classes = java.lang.System
introspector.restrict.classes = java.lang.Thread
introspector.restrict.classes = java.lang.ThreadGroup
introspector.restrict.classes = java.lang.ThreadLocal
```

Answer (score 1):

There are too many things in Java which could cause a problem that you might not be aware of.  The safest thing to do is to create a list of classes which are allows and run these via a custom class loader in a separate process (so you can kill it safely)

For serious dangerous code which most people don't even know is there have a look at [sun.misc.Unsafe](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/misc/Unsafe.java.html) which allows you to

- Access random areas of memory.
- Create new instance of classes without calling a constructor e.g. new instances of Enums.
- lock and unlock an objects monitor discretely. (Without a synchronized block)